# Change Status Bar color in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I searched for a long time to find a solution to change the color of the Status Bar in my app. Actually I'm using min API 14 so I can't use the methods from the lollipop version.

Is there any way to change the Status Bar color for API 14+?
(I've seen an app on the Play Store which have changed the color, I've API 19 on my phone)

Comment: have you tried using colorPrimary 9 in your theme something like  <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

Comment: this will change the color to white  and you may choose any color.See if it helps your cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change status bar color in kitkat (API 19) and above with [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library but no change in older versions.

Comment: you're right, unfortunately it's not possible under kitkat (API 19)